# What constructor use

Tags: c++

I must design a class int2d inheriting from `vector<vector<int>>`, so that the following code :

```
int main() 
{ 
    int2d t1(4, 3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        { 
            t1(i, j) = i + j;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    { 
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << t1(i, j) << " "; 
        {
            cout<<endl; 
        }
    } 
}
```

... produces the following result:

```
0 1 2
1 2 3 
2 3 4 
3 4 5
```

I already wrote :

```
class int2d : public vector<vector<int>> {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    int a;
    int b;

    //vector<int> tmp;
    //vector<vector<int>> vec(b);
    int2d(int a, int b) {

        vector<int> tmp(b);
        vector<vector<int>> vec(a);
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            vec.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }

    int2d& operator = (const int2d& X){
        if (this == &X)
            return *this;
        int2d tmp(X.a, X.b);
    }

    int2d& operator = (const int& X){
        vec[a][b] = X;
    }
};
```

But how can I make `t1(i, j) = i + j;` compile and work ?

Comment: You have to [overload the function call operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/function_call_operator_overloading.htm)

Comment: Why does int2d inherit from vector?

Comment: My code dosent work, i cant compile it .

Comment: There's probably 0 reason to inherit from vector. AFAIK, it's not meant to be extended.

Comment: Do you really want to use `t1(...)` or did you intend to write `t1[i][j]=i+j`?

Comment: Thats ambiguous task from my professor. If there was t1[i][j]=i+j, there wouldnt be problem my friend :D

Answer (score 0):

You just need `operator()(std::size_t, std::size_t)` probably both `const` and non-`const` overloads too.

I would highly recommend against inheriting from standard containers though. Just have the standard container as a member inside your class.

Comment: Using composition over inheritance is a hard lesson that I've been learning lately.